NPM install error - Themeforest Template React
i just download template from themeforest, so i can learn and practice my JS skills. Unfortunately i have problem at the beginning. I can't instal package.json.

npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: tradio@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@16.14.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^16.13.1" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0" from react-rangeslider@2.2.0
npm error node_modules/react-rangeslider
npm error   react-rangeslider@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error

I tried npm install --legacy-peer-deps,  npm install --force and still got errors. I'm sure, i'm in correct folder. Package has probably old version of react but idk how to fix it. I tried downgrade node to 15 and 16..  Can i do something about it?
PACKAGE.JSON FILE
{
    "name": "tradio",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "apexcharts": "^3.19.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.7",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
        "react-datepicker": "^3.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-modal-video": "^1.2.3",
        "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
        "react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
        "react-scrollspy-nav": "^1.2.4",
        "react-slick": "^0.26.1",
        "react-tradingview-widget": "^1.3.2",
        "recharts": "^1.8.5",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "sass": "node-sass --watch src/scss/main.scss src/css/style.css --source-map src/css/style.css.map"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}



Check the peer dependencies of react-rangeslider@^2.0.0 package:
$ npm view react-rangeslider@^2.0.0 peerDependencies
{ react: '^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0' }

But you have installed react@^16.13.1 in your project. That's why npm throws this error.
Solution:

Ask the maintainer to update the peer dependencies for the package if it is compatible with React 16. This issue is here.

You can try to install it using npm install react-rangeslider --legacy-peer-deps . But there may be potential risks that are not compatible.

Downgrade the react to ^15.0.0 version.

react-rangeslider@^2.0.0 package is too old, try find alternative package.


